# Сложный запрос SQL (объединение таблиц)

Tags: mysql, join

Есть 3 таблицы:

> 1. FIRM: | id | title |
> 2. OFFICE: | id | title | firm_id | city_id |
> 3. CITY: | id | title |

Как достать `title` всех `FIRM`, чьи `OFFICE` есть в `CITY` по `CITY.id`?

Comment: Сложный запрос - это простой join... Надо бы как-то более конкретно вопрос назвать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выберем `FIRM.title` по указанному значению `CITY.id`, присоединив таблички `FIRM` и `OFFICE` по совпадению ключей, а также сгруппировав результат по `FIRM.id`, заодно избавившись тем самым от дубликатов:

```
SELECT FIRM.title FROM CITY 
        LEFT JOIN OFFICE ON OFFICE.city_id = CITY.id 
        LEFT JOIN FIRM ON OFFICE.firm_id = FIRM.id 
    WHERE CITY.id = 1 
GROUP BY FIRM.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select f.title from firm f inner join office o on o.firm_id = f.id where o.city_id = 1
```

Или, при необходимости

```
select distinct f.title from firm f inner join office o on o.firm_id = f.id where o.city_id = 1
```

Comment: Товарищ, советую добавить `DISTINCT` или, что, как мне кажется, правильне, `GROUP BY`, ибо Ваш запрос возвращает дубликаты названий фирм)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, интересно что я сначала написал distinct, но потом решил, что он не нужен и удалил. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: ну, таки чисто по логике, в одном городе может быть несколько филиалов некой фирмы. Особенно если «фирмой» является сеть продуктовых магазинов ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯